# How to click on the dropdown item with text as (Select All) with Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, drop-down-menu, webdriverwait

edit: On this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdjih.png), I am trying to submit parameters for a report to be generated from a database.  I have been able to send_keys() with a new start date for the first field.  The second field (end date) stays the same.  For the 3rd field and on, except for one, I need to click on `(Select All)`.

I need to click on `(Select All)`, which shows in a hidden dropdown table only after clicking the parent 'divDropDown'. When activated, this hidden table shows up with a tbody in which 5-6 tr/td/span sets hold the various options. You can find the select all option under id `ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00`.
Further up in the HTML there's a dropDownButton which doesn't generate errors in the code(first 2 lines) but also doesn't show on the browser as activating that dropdown as it does manually, so I'm thinking it doesn't help here.

I've searched for relevant answers and tried various bits of code (wait, execute_script, etc) within Selenium to access this item, and even tried to switch to the iframe above it (which seems to activate when clicking on the input area even though the elements sought are outside of it), but still get error 'Unable to locate element...'
Here are various code tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07"]')#.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_ddDropDownButton"]').click()

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown"]').click()
#driver.execute_script("event.cancelBubble=true;")
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_HiddenIndices" and @type="hidden"]')

#elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00" and @type="checkbox"]')#.click()
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*div[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown"]/.//span[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00"]').get_attribute("innerHTML")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem1)
selector = '#ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00'
selector = '#ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown > span > div:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > span > label'
path = '//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown"]/span/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/span/input'#label'
#path = '//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00"]'
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(path).click()
```

I believe it's unable to locate element because it is typically hidden, but no matter how I try to click or execute the dropdown, via the button or clicking the div, it won't stay open (I do see it flash down sometimes, it just recloses and thus the table, and it's dropdown, is hidden again).  I've also tried the following code to test it. With the regular wait command, I would get the 'stale element' error after some iterations. Without any wait, I'd get element not found.  With the 'wait until', I can see the dropdown going up/down, but cannot seem to catch the 'select all' when it's visible? All this does is open/close the dropdown with my print statements to see when (after printing 'checking if exists'). I've also tried to execute directly 'select all's script `"$get('ctl31_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnSelectAllClick(this);"` to no avail.

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True

for i in range(15):
    #driver.implicitly_wait(1000)
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_ddDropDownButton"]').click()
    wait(driver, 1000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_ddDropDownButton"]'))).click()
    #elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00"]')
    print('checking if exists')
    if check_exists_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00"]'):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00"]').click()
        print('did it!')
    else: print('past dropdown button %d' % i)
    i +=1
```

Here is the HTML (it's a login website so I can't show much else, sorry for the pic: [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDuAs.png)

```
<iframe id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_ctl01" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:10;" src="javascript:'';" frameBorder="0" title="Borough: place holder" longdesc="Borough: place holder" Name="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_ctl01"></iframe>
<div id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;" style="display:inline-block;border-color:DarkGray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;overflow:auto;background-color:window;display:none;position:absolute;z-index:11;">
    <span style="margin: 0px; background-color: window;"><div style="overflow: auto; width: 186px; height: 133px;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:window;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap">
                            <span>
                                <input id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00" type="checkbox" name="ctl31$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl00" onclick="$get('ctl31_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnSelectAllClick(this);"><label for="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00">(Select All)</label>
                            </span></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl01" type="checkbox" name="ctl31$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl01" onclick="$get('ctl31_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00');"><label for="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl01">MANHATTAN&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></span></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl02" type="checkbox" name="ctl31$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl02" onclick="$get('ctl31_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00');"><label for="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl02">BROOKLYN&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></span></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl03" type="checkbox" name="ctl31$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl03" onclick="$get('ctl31_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00');"><label for="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl03">QUEENS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></span></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl04" type="checkbox" name="ctl31$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl04" onclick="$get('ctl31_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00');"><label for="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl04">BRONX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></span></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl05" type="checkbox" name="ctl31$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl05" onclick="$get('ctl31_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00');"><label for="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl05">STATEN&nbsp;ISLAND&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></span></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="ctl31$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$HiddenIndices" id="ctl31_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_HiddenIndices" value="">
        </div>
        <div style="height: 16px; width: 100%; margin: 0px; border-top: 1px solid lightgray; background-color: window; direction: ltr;"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

and here's how the webpage looks: [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdjih.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you help us updating the question with the exact _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_ along with the text based HTML (instead/in-addition of the picture of the HTML which you have provided) so we can help you out?

Comment: I tried to add more info and post text html, though is there a better/easier way to do it? On dev tools I can't seem to select/copy by section, and by 'view source' it's quite ugly, plus it's missing some hidden elements. Maybe I'm missing a setting within SO post. @DebanjanB

Comment: thank you! I just did a re-edit to fix it up as much as I could...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the dropdown option with text as **(Select All)** as the elements are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, '_divDropDown') and contains(@onclick, 'cancelBubble')][contains(@onactivate, 'cancelBubble')]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, '_divDropDown') and contains(@onclick, 'cancelBubble')][contains(@onactivate, 'cancelBubble')]/span/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span//label[contains(@for, '_divDropDown_') and contains(., '(Select All)')]"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Tried this, but I get a TimeOutException because it can't find `_divDropDown`.  I changed the first line to find the `_ddDropDownButton` as had been working before, but then it timed out again on the second line, looking for the `divDropDown` again. Can't seem to click on it.  The difference here is that it's underneath that iframe, which lights up in chrome devtools when I manually click on that area along with the `divDropDown`, so although it's not within the iframe, it seems to be connected to it.

Comment: stranger still, I'm randomly adjusting the times on the wait, and got the 'Lot Status' field to `(Select All)` and it stopped with the 'Lot Type' field dropped down. It ran past the first 'Borough' field without selecting all but didn't stop the code with errors.  Changing the seconds, I get either a TimeOut or Stale Exception.  I thought wait 'until' should get the timing right no matter what, right?

Comment: ended up getting through the form with an illogical assortment of waits, repeat clicks and so on.  Not sure why the code to click on the dropdown button, then the div, then the option wouldn't work always, with the explicit waits. But at least I am able to submit.  Now I have a similar problem in clicking on a disabled button to access another dropdown to save the report.